# Poor ListView performance on Gluon

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile

I have a custom `ListCell` implementation, shown in the picture below.

[image]

The left side, which represents the date, consisting of 3 labels, put in a `VBox` and the "CounterContent" consisting of the counter, with a `TextField` for each digit, contained in a `HBox`, and two `Hboxes` containing labels for kWh, kWh/day and so on. And that seem to be just too much, to be running performantly.

I've tried to load the data in a background task, showing a progress indicator, while the task is running, but unlike on desktop, on android the performance is very poor. Whenever I switch to the listview, the garbage collection kicks in, and blocks the ui thread, so that the progress indicator never shows up.

I've tried it on a Huawei Y-300, Android 4.1.1, javafxports 8.60.6 (because javafxports 8.60.7 causes a bug, that makes `TextField` unusable), and on a Samsung S5 mini, Android 5+. On the Samsung phone the performance in general is way better, just like expected, because of the Ahead-of-Time compilation I guess, but there is still the garbage collection issue. Furthermore after the listview has been populated with cells, the scrolling is not very smooth.

Is the listcell to complex or what else could be the matter for the poor performance?

**UPDATE:**

After running a lot of tests it seems the unsmooth scrolling is not caused by performance problems. At least on the S5 (javafxports 8.60.7).

I removed all css styling, and replaced the textfields by a single label (the counter node is already a custom control(forgot about that), which lays out the textfields in 2 `Regions`(not `HBoxes`) and the nodes of the `ListCell` are instantiated in the constructor). Furthermore I switched the `ListView` for a `CharmListView` and set android.monocle.input.touchRadius=1.

None of these steps resulted in considerable improvement.

Just to clarify: In contrast to the Huawei phone, the scrolling on the S5 and android 5+ is usable, but it's not very smooth, which makes for a unsatisfactory user experience.

On the Huawei (javafxports 8.60.6), changing the counter textfields for a label, gave a significant improvement, but not to the point where the scrolling became usable. Until I set this magical experimental switch: gluon.experimental.performance=true, which makes the listview scrolling lightning fast(after a little warmup delay), but still not really smooth.

Answer (score 5):

There are many reasons why the performance of a complex scene is reduced, so this is just a list of possible ideas that might help improving it, in any order.

*ListCell*

For starters, the number of nodes in the cell is really high. Notice that every single scroll you make means the full rendering of the virtual flow that holds the visible cells. And for every cell, that means recreating its content all over again.

Without viewing your code I can't tell, but you should avoid creating new instances of every node in the cell all the time, by having just one single instance, and in the `updateItem` method only change the content of the nodes.

Have a look at this [sample](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/samples/src/master/Notes/). The `NoteCell` class is a custom cell, where a `ListTile` is used.

*Number of nodes*

Have you tried using just a `Label` to replace the 8 textfields and 3 boxes?

*Cache*

If you use images downloaded from Internet, use Gluon Charm Down `Cache` to avoid the same image being downloaded over and over again.

Have a look at this [sample](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/samples/src/master/FiftyStates/). Without the cache, even on desktop the performance is really affected.

Also use the JavaFX built-in cache for any node, trying different cache strategies.

*CSS*

Complex CSS requires long CPU time. Try to simplify it. Even you can remove the whole CSS for a quick test. Then decide what you may or may not use.

The same goes for animations: Avoid animations, transitions or even CSS effects, if possible.

*Custom Control*

The counter complex node could probably be replaced by a custom control that optimizes the rendering.

*CharmListView*

Have you tried using the Gluon Charm `CharmListView` control instead of the `ListView`?

There's a new experimental flag that you can use to test a possible optimization that might improve performance while scrolling the list. Set `gluon.experimental.performance=true` on the `java.custom.properties` file, and give it a try.

*JavaFXPorts version*

You mentioned you are using 8.60.6 because of the TextField bug. In this case, are your `TextField` nodes editable? If not, I'd suggest replacing them with other nodes and running with 8.60.7, since it contains a lot of performance improvements.

*Performance tools*

Use performance tools like [Monitor](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monitor.html) and use its [profiling](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) options so you can trace down any possible bottle neck.

*CPU*

Last but not least: your mobile device specs are always critical.

Trying to render a complex scene on a Cortex A5, given that "it is the smallest, lowest cost and lowest power ARMv7 application [processor](http://www.arm.com/products/processors/cortex-a/cortex-a5.php)", or using a very old Android 4.1.1, can't perform as well as running it on a brand new device with higher specs.

As you also mentioned, running on a Cortex A7 performs "way better". Have a look at this [comparison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_ARMv7-A_cores), and find the right architecture for the job.

Anyway, there's always room for improvement, and a lot of effort is put into it. Your feedback is always welcome.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed information! I've updated my question with the steps I took, to further investigate the issue

Comment: Glad you are getting some improvements. Did you try the 2015 Gluon's [JavaOne](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gluonhq.applications.javaone) app? It uses a quite performant  `CharmListView` control, but without the experimental flag yet. Check if scrolling goes smooth in your devices.

Comment: Just tried it, seeing the same little "jumps" while scrolling, so my list cell implementation is not causing this effect, as I expected in the begining.  Scrolling in a Webview e.g. is super smooth.

Comment: It seemed that the large amount of layout containers (4 hBoxes, 2 vBoxes) had the biggest impact on the performace. After having replaced them with a custom component, which takes care of the layout, the performance has improved significantly, and it makes no difference if the experimental switch is used or not.

Comment: I just realized the super smooth scrolling of the `CharmListView`, for the short moment when a `headerCell` and the `floatingHeaderCell` are "connected". Could this behaviour be applied to the scrolling in general? (I know I'm constantly asking the same question, but I'm still unhappy with the scrolling performance, especially because 1 of my one apps [Orienteering](https://github.com/j-ns/Orienteering) shows very smooth scrolling, which I'm just not able to reproduce. Used the same ListCells, styleSheets, even tried to remove the fab layer, to see if it makes a difference.)

Comment: Setting a fixedCellSize for the ListView shows a significant improvement in the creation of ListCells, i.e. whenever the ListCells are created from scratch instead of being reused