# How to change the behavior of JavaFX ListView to become like that Android ListView

Tags: javafx-8, javafxports, gluon-mobile

Im developing a **JavaFX Application** to be deployed in **Android** but somehow Im facing these problems in JavaFX **ListView**:

- **scrolling** is not smooth, very **laggy**
- everytime you press on the **item** of the List, there is a delay in its **focus**
- when you register an **setOnMouseClick Event**, it is being executed when you **scroll** the List (not the same on Android)

How to overcome this problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the laggy scrolling issue, check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36819513/poor-listview-performance-on-gluon), for a list of possible hints on how performance could be improved.

The Gluon's `CharmListView` control has been designed precisely with those hints.

Try it including the experimental flag (since Charm 2.1.1): Set `gluon.experimental.performance=true` on the `java.custom.properties` file that should be placed under /src/android/resources`.